# jsconfig.json in sfdx project

Tags: lightning-web-components, configuration, git, js

Let's say we have got (for some reasons) from git jsconfig.json file in /lwc directory. My questions are :

- for what purposes do we need to use this file at all in project?
- i can see in `include` section something like `...../.sfdx/typings/...d.ts files. what  purposes is for? (those ones appear in git repository and i need to exclude them from commit)

so what can i do with this?
do i need to adjust my .gitignore? is so could anyone show me the to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsconfig.json file tells the compiler where to find auto-complete support for import statements, and set options that will prevent spurious errors when editing LWC JavaScript files. If you do not include this file, you will get additional errors and lose some auto-complete functionality for your LWC JavaScript files. The .d.ts files are used to provide auto-complete support. If you do not have these files, then some auto-complete functionality will not be available. If you're not using VS Code, you can remove these files, but it is recommended you have them there for the best developer experience.

Comment: how about .gitignore? if i use git add . that files (i mean *.*.ts) have been staged and then go to remote repo. How can I avoid this behaivior?

Comment: @pincet Why would you *not* want them there? They're supposed to be there.

Comment: @pincet To be clear, the jsconfig.json should be there. The typings directory is not included by the .sfdx in .gitignore. Those files are created on the fly by the DX bundle.

Comment: for some reasons we can see .sfdx folder in remote git repo and i need to avoid that kind of behaviuor. I do want to have this folder in my local project but not on remote

Comment: @pincet Yes, .sfdx should not be included in your repo, and should be in .gitignore. You will need to remove it from the working index. The jsconfig.json file should still be stored in the repo, though, as VS Code needs it.